# send message from textarea to determined email address with python in web2py

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}  
<h1>Send Email</h1>  
<form method='post'>  
    <input type='text' name='name'/>  
    <input type='text' name='email'/>  
    <input type='text' name='subject'/>  
    <textarea rows="6" name="message" cols="31"></textarea></p>  
    <input type='submit' value='Send' />  
</form>  
<h3>  
    Email sent {{=}}  
</h3>
```

I created one textbox, one text area and one button for sending Email in view section in web2py. I want to create UI area. user should write name and text and after clicking on SEND button those name and text should be sent to an specific email address. I am a beginner in python and  I need your help for writing related code in controller section and maybe other codes in view section.

I just have this code in the page Email.html on view section but I didn't know what should I write here-->   {{=}}
moreover I don't have any code in controller!

Comment: Add code samples of what you have so we can get a better understanding of what you want and what you done already

Comment: I inserted the code.